Series of confluent hypergeometric functions with one extra Pochhamer symbol
I'm trying to solve analytically the integral
$$Z = \int_0^a \exp(-\alpha x^4 - \beta x^2 - \gamma) \mathrm{d}{x}.$$
To do this, I wrote it as
$$Z = e^{-\gamma} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \beta^n}{n!} \int_0^a \exp(-\alpha x^4) x^{2n} \mathrm{d}{x}.$$
After substituting $x^4 = u a^4$, it is possible to reduce the expression to a series of confluent hypergeometric functions,
$$Z = a e^{-\gamma} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (a^2 \beta)^n}{n!} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_n} M\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{4};\frac{n}{2}+\frac{5}{4};-\alpha a^4\right).$$
By splitting the series into $n$ even and $n$ odd, we can get the expression down to
$$Z = a e^{-\gamma} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(a^2 \beta)^{2k}}{2^{2k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k k!} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{k}}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{k}} M\left(k+\frac{1}{4};k+\frac{5}{4};-\alpha a^4\right) - \frac{a^3 \beta e^{-\gamma}}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(a^2 \beta)^{2k}}{2^{2k} k! \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_k} \frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{k}}{\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)_{k}} M\left(k +\frac{3}{4};k+\frac{7}{4};-\alpha a^4\right).$$
My question then is: How can I sum up these series? If there was one less Pochhammer symbol, it would be possible to use the identity
$$M(a,b,x+y) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(a)_n y^n}{(b)_n n!} M(a+n,b+n,x),$$
but the extra Pochhammer symbol seems to spoil this.

What makes you think there is a closed-form solution?

If you solve this PDE you can actually obtain a closed form (with BC ofc):
$$4\alpha\dfrac{\partial Z}{\partial\alpha}+2\beta\dfrac{\partial Z}{\partial\beta}+Z=a\cdot\exp(-\alpha,a^4-\beta, a^2-\gamma)$$

@RobertIsrael Hope, mostly hahaha. But I guessed there might be a summation formula for hypergeometric functions that covers this case, although it may be less known. I also know that the case $a \to +\infty$ does have a closed-form solution

Why not to use the gamma function ?

@ClaudeLeibovici That is a possibility, but I thought it would be easier to sum confluent hypergeometric functions than incomplete gamma functions. I tried both ways, but found a bit more literature (namely the addition theorem in the question) with the confluent approach

The answer to the question is to write the confluent hypergeometric series in summation form. Then reduce as many, or join, components as one can to an index of the form $(x)_{p \, n + q \, k}$ over summation index $n$ and $k$. The result is a double series and leaves one to find the two variable hypergeometric series that fits the resulting form. This can be seen by the following.
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(a^2 \beta)^{2k}}{2^{2k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k k!} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{k}}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{k}} M\left(k+\frac{1}{4};k+\frac{5}{4};-\alpha a^4\right) \\
&= \sum_{n,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{k}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{k} \, \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{k}} \, \frac{\left(k+\frac{1}{4}\right)_{n}}{\left(k + \frac{5}{4}\right)_{n}} \, \frac{(\beta \, a^2/2)^{2k}}{k!} \, \frac{(-\alpha \, a^4)^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{n+k}}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)_{n+k} \, \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{k}} \, \frac{(\beta \, a^2/2)^{2k}}{k!} \, \frac{(-\alpha \, a^4)^n}{n!} \\
&= F_{1:1, 0}^{1:0, 0}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1/4: \, --; \, --; \\ 5/4: \, 1/2; \, --; \end{array} \, \frac{\beta^2 \, a^4}{4} \, - \alpha \, a^4 \, \right),
\end{align}
where $F(...)$ is the Kampé de Fériet function. The proposed series can be placed into the form
\begin{align}
e^{\gamma} \, Z &= a \, F_{1:1, 0}^{1:0, 0}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1/4: \, --; \, --; \\ 5/4: \, 1/2; \, --; \end{array} \, \frac{\beta^2 \, a^4}{4} \, - \alpha \, a^4 \, \right) \\ 
& \hspace{10mm} - \frac{a^3 \beta}{3} \, F_{1:1, 0}^{1:0, 0}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3/4: \, --; \, --; \\ 7/4: \, 3/2; \, --; \end{array} \, \frac{\beta^2 \, a^4}{4} \, - \alpha \, a^4 \, \right). 
\end{align}
Alternatively consider an expansion as follows.
Let
$$ I = \int_{0}^{a} e^{- \alpha \, x^4 - \beta \, x^2 - \gamma} \, dx. $$
Expanding $ e^{- \alpha \, x^4} $ leads to
\begin{align}
e^{\gamma} \, I &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha)^{n}}{n!} \, \int_{0}^{a} x^{4 n} \, e^{-\beta \, x^2} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha/\beta^2)^{n}}{n!} \, \int_{0}^{\beta \, a^2} e^{-t} \, t^{2n-1/2} \, dt \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha/\beta^2)^{n}}{n!} \, \left( \Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}, \, \beta \, a^2 \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi \, \beta}}{2 \, \sqrt{\alpha + \beta^2}} - \frac{1}{2 \, \sqrt{\beta}} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha/\beta^2)^{n}}{n!} \, \Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}, \, \beta \, a^2 \right),
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(n ,x)$ is an incomplete gamma function. If there is a desire to make in more complicated than this then by using a confluent hypergeometric definition of the incomplete gamma function the series becomes
\begin{align}
e^{\gamma} \, I &= \frac{1}{2 \, \sqrt{\beta}} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha/\beta^2)^n}{n!} \, \frac{2}{4n+1} \, (\beta \, a^2)^{2n+1/2} \, {}_{1}F_{1}(2n+1/2; \, 2n+3/2; \, - \beta \, a^2) \\
&= a \, \sum_{n,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2)_{2n+k}}{(3/2)_{2n+k}} \, \frac{(-\alpha \, a^4)^n}{n!} \, \frac{(- \beta \, a^2)^k}{k!} \\
&= a \, F_{1:0; 0}^{1:0; 0}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} [1/2: 2, 1]; \, --; \, --; \\ [3/2: 2, 1]; \, --; \, --; \end{array} \, - \alpha \, a^4, \, - \beta \, a^2 \, \right),
\end{align}
where this last series is the Srivastava-Daoust series.
Note that there may be some reductions of the series when certain parameters align. This is left as an exercise for the reader. Also note that the demonstration of two expansion methods leads to a application of connecting a particular Srivastava-Daoust series to two Kampé de Fériet functions.

The last hypergeometric function looks fairly simple. Is there no reduction formula for it?

@ТymaGaidash   There may be cases where the Srivastava-Daoust series shown reduces to something more "usable". Certainly if $- \beta , a^2 = 1$ or $- \alpha , a^4 = 1$ there should be.  For other reductions to consider is left as an exercise for the reader.
